# Could not link boost using mingw32-g++

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, mingw, linker-errors

I'm trying to get boost::asio work.

I've built the boost with command

```
bjam toolset=gcc --build-type=complete --with-system --with-thre
ad --with-date_time --with-regex --with-serialization stage
```

My `libboost_system` file is called `libboost_system-mgw47-1_53.dll`. So I tried to compile an example [program](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp) with command (tried both with slashes and back-slashes)

```
mingw32-g++ -ID:/boost_1_53_0 -LD:/boost_1_53_0/bin.v2/libs
main.cpp -libboost_system-mgw47-1_53
```

But I continue getting an error

```
ld.exe: cannot find -libboost_system-mgw47-1_53
```

The library file is present: `D:\boost_1_53_0\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-mingw-4.7.2\release\libboost_system-mgw47-1_53.dll`. What I'm doing wrong? I tell the compiler where to look for binaries. Why can't it find them?

P.S. building on a x64 Win7 with mingw 4.7

Comment: I believe you need to use `mingw32-g++ -ID:/boost_1_53_0 -LD:/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib
main.cpp -lboost_system-mgw47-1_53`.

Comment: @cv_and_he thanks for an answer! I did not know all the built binaries are stored in this folder! In fact my problem was that I did not know the `-L` option does not scan child folders. After changing to `-LD:\boost_1_53_0\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-mingw-4.7.2\release` the compiler did found the library. But your solutions seems to be much more better. Thank you. You could probably post an answer, so I can accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
mingw32-g++ -ID:/boost_1_53_0 -LD:/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib main.cpp -lboost_system-mgw47-1_53
```

Answer (score 1):

The linker could not find the library file because `-L` option does not search files in child directories.

One of the possible solutions was to specify the complete path to the library directory `-LD:\boost_1_53_0\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-mingw-4.7.2\release`.

The other - to specify the full path to the library file itself `D:\boost_1_53_0\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-mingw-4.7.2\release\libboost_system-mgw47-1_53.dll`. No `-libboost_system-mgw47-1_53` is needed in this case.

And the most correct one was written by @cv_and_he